# Pronunciation of I'll

Tags: pronunciation, american-english

Do Americans pronounce ‘I’ll’ as ‘all [ɔ:l]' as an American ESL teacher says, frequently?

[[Her YouTube Channel]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaJIb2y6MQA)
[image]

Comment: When I'm not speaking slowly and carefully, I pronounce *I'll* as /ɑl/ (with the vowel of *father* and *pollen*, not of *all*). But the dictionaries say it rhymes with *tile*, and from the answers, it seems that there are a lot of Americans who pronounce it "correctly".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*I'll* and *all* are homophones in many dialects, including mine. In many other dialects, *I'll*, *isle*, and *aisle* are homophones. Generally, either of these pronunciations will apply. It seems that the first is more common in American dialects and that the second is more common in British dialects.

Comment: I think OP needs to recognise Wikipedia's point, that [Phonemic differentiation may vary between different dialects of a language, so that a particular minimal pair in one accent is a pair of homophones in another.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_pair) Asking how "Americans" pronounce some particular phonological element doesn't seem particularly constructive. To my ear, in a "cut glass" upper-class British accent, **I'll** sounds like **earl**, and I doubt I could hear any difference between the contracted verb and the nobleman, coming from such a speaker.

Comment: +1 for _I'll_ being much closer to _aisle_ than _all_.  That's the way this North American says it.

Comment: I'm no expert on American pronunciation (which obviously varies by region / time / sociolinguistic community), but if I imagine a typical *uneducated cowboy/hillbilly* saying *"Well I'll be darned!"* those first two vowels seem like homophones to me - *"Wahl arle be darned!"*.

Comment: Her "I'll" is not so much a homophone to her claimed "all" than a schwa or perhaps "uhll". In my own (SE England) speech, it's normally "aisle" but in unstressed rapid speech may become "ahll" and even a slight 'r' towards "ahrll".

Comment: It's more common in American dialects?  Which American dialects?

Answer (score 4):

I already lived with an American boy and I remember the fact that he pronounced "I'll" approximately as "all", so this sounds true for me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'll is not really pronounced the same as isle or aisle in American English in normal speech. When said to read "I'll" in an isolated position some people might pronounce it as isle or aisle. In reality it is always pronounced as if it rhymes with doll in American English. It is a similar situation with the word "to." If isolated (or in quotation marks like I just did) Americans will pronounce the same as too or two. However, it is almost always pronounced with a schwa unless it's at the end of a sentence, for example: "I don't want to." Regarding the pronunciation of "all" and "I'll" being the same, in the General American accent, they are not. I have seen the Rachel's English videos before and I would have to say that is the main problem that I have with her. She teaches the cot-caught merger which is not standard. So, in conclusion "I'll" is not pronounced like "all" or "isle/aisle" in the General American accent. It is pronounced like "doll" but without the d.

Comment: This is factually incorrect; while it may be true in some regions, I can attest that in most of the South there's no aural distinction between "aisle" and "I'll".

Comment: I was not speaking of regions of the United States I was only speaking of General American.

Comment: There's no such thing as "General American".

Comment: If you look it up, it does exist and there are several regional accents that are comparable to it.

Answer (score 0):

In American English, *I'll* [aɪl] is usually pronounced as "*al*," much like "*isle*." A common example would be ***I'll go to the store later.*** Which sounds like ***Al go to the store later.*** When the word's length is dragged out, it has a more southern accent, while when it is short and crisp, it is more like a northern accent.

Note that it is not pronounced "Ahh-l".

Comment: _Al_ rhymes with _pal_, and _I'll_ rhymes with _while_. While some dialects might pronounce _al_ and _I'll_ similarly, I don't think that's a good way to describe how to pronounce "I'll". It's also worth noting that "all" (which is what the O.P. inquired about) and "al" (which is what you have in your answer) are **not** pronounced the same.

Comment: @J.R.: I agree that *I'll* rhymes with *while*, but do both of these rhyme with *tile* or *tall*?

Comment: @PeterShor: Yes to _tile_, most certainly not with _tall_, although I've moved around the U.S. a lot – enough to know that I'd be naive to strongly aver that _no one_ rhymes those. (I've known some folks who pronounce "pen" and "pin" as near homophones, for example, but that's more the exception than the rule.)

Comment: @J.R.: I am fairly sure that many of the Americans who pronounce *I'll* to rhyme with *all* do the same thing with *while*, but not *tile*. I do this myself when I'm not speaking slowly and carefully.

Comment: @PeterShor: I don't recall hearing that, but I'll be on the lookout for it. Note: the (sometimes-rhyming?) words _recall_ and _I'll_ are intentionally embedded in my response. :^) On a side note, I had a friend from Richmond, Virginia who rhymed "oil" and "bowl"; I wouldn't call that "standard" pronunciation, but I obviously can't call it "invalid," either – that's the way he said it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses- I was unclear in the pronunciation, as I was originally aiming for a homonym of "isle." I edited the answer for clarification.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it's always pronounced the same as *all* in American English.

Comment: “Always” is a pretty strong word here, with 300,000,000 people speaking American English, plus a wide array of local accents. Moreover, the dictionaries disagree with your answer; if you look at the pronunciation guides, [_I'll_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/i-ll) is listed as a homophone of [_aisle_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/aisle), not [_all_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/all).